Is it acceptable to omit the noun when mentioning it for a second time?
In English, it would be quite natural to say:
In Chinese schools, there are forty pupils in a class, while in English schools, there are only thirty.
It is not necessary to restate "thirty pupils" at the end, even though that is the meaning.
Is the same possible in Chinese? Would it be correct to say:
在中国学校，一个班有四十名学生，而在英国学校，只有三十名。

The question reminds me of a thought-provoking sentence, which is also a Chinese meme now. 在我的后园，可以看见墙外有两株树，一株是枣树，还有一株也是枣树。 --Lu Xun, Autumn Night.

Yes, it’s possible and your example sentence is correct.
Explanation and another example from 量词’s wiki page:

如果上下文允许，名词也可以被省略，而只用数词和分类词。


问：“多少桶水？”（“桶”是量词）
答：“两桶。”（省略了“水”）

